# AWS Data Transfer Fee

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am thinking of creating an AWS instance that is able to handle a large amount of data transfer, approximately 10GB/hours, and found that the default EC2 data transfer cost is very expensive for this purpose. I just find out about the ELB (Elastic Load Balancing), which offers a more affordable cost for handling such large data transfer.

I have never used ELB before on my instance, so I wonder if using ELB can significantly reduce the cost of handling large data transfers. Any opinions about this?

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us more about your use-case. For example, will this data be mostly sent _TO_ users (eg like Netflix), or will most of the data be sent _FROM_ users (eg streaming data for analysis)? What do you mean by "10GB/hours"? Do you mean "10GB every hour"? At 9c/GB, that would only be 90c/hour or $650/month. Is this too expensive for you? What is your business model? Please edit your question to provide this information rather than via a comment.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing in the ELB pricing is "data processing cost" which is in addition to data transfer cost. An ELB isn't going to help you save money on data transfer, it's actually going to add costs to your total bill.

When you say you have "large amount of data transfer" is it incoming data, or outgoing, or both? Note that the two are billed very differently in AWS, with incoming data usually being free, and outgoing data usually being exorbitantly, prohibitively expensive.

Also, what is this data? Is it static files? Or is it some sort of massive amount of dynamic data you are generating? Is it something a CDN could cache, in order to drastically reduce how much data you have to serve from your EC2 instance?

For the amount of data transfer you are talking about, if you can't cache it somewhere in a CDN (not CloudFront, but a CDN with relatively decent bandwidth pricing) then you need to contact AWS sales department to see what data transfer volume discount they can offer you. And you should contact some other cloud providers and ask them the same thing.